# Almost all of the constructors and deconstructors in my classes are implicitly defined as deleted?

Tags: c++

Variable.h

```
#pragma once

#include <unordered_map>

namespace ssu
{
    class GenericArray;

    class Variable
    {
        enum Type
        {
            NONE,

            BOOL,
            STRING,
            INT,
            FLOAT,

            ARRAY,
            DICT,

            TYPE_MAX
        };
    private:
        template<typename Key, typename Value>
        using Dictionary = std::unordered_map<Key, Value>;

        union
        {
            bool _bool;
            std::string _string;
            int64_t _int;
            double _float;

            GenericArray _array;
            Dictionary<std::string, Variable&> _dict;
        };

        Type m_Type;
    private:
        static inline Variable eval();
    public:
        Variable(const bool p_bool);
        Variable(const std::string p_string);
        Variable(const int64_t p_int);
        Variable(const double p_float);
        Variable(const GenericArray p_array);
        Variable(const Dictionary<std::string, Variable&> p_dict);
    };

    class GenericArray
    {
    private:
        struct Block
        {
            Variable m_Data;
            Block* m_Next;
            Block* m_Prev;
        };

        Block* m_First;
        Block* m_Last;

        size_t m_Size = 0;
    public:
        void push_back(Variable p_var);
        void erase(int index);
        void erase(int first, int end);

        Variable& operator[] (int index);
    };
}
```

Variable.cpp

```
#include "variable.h"

namespace ssu
{
    void GenericArray::push_back(Variable p_var)
    {
        Block* block = new Block;
        block->m_Data = p_var;

        if (!m_First || !m_Last)
        {
            m_First = block;
            m_Last = block;
        }
    }
}
```

I am extremely confused by the errors I'm getting. I've tried compiling the code, but it won't build. This never happened before.

In case it matters, the `Variable` class is intended to be used as a generic type for all of the values in the union. Maybe the recursion between `GenericArray` and `Variable` is contributing to the problem?

These are the types of errors I'm getting:

```
File    Severity    Code    Line    Description
variable.cpp    Error   C2280   6   'ssu::Variable::~Variable(void)': attempting to reference a deleted function
variable.cpp    Error   E1790   7   the default constructor of "ssu::GenericArray::Block" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
variable.cpp    Error   E1776   8   function "ssu::Variable::operator=(const ssu::Variable &)" (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
variable.h      Error   C2079   36  'ssu::Variable::_array' uses undefined class 'ssu::GenericArray'
variable.h      Warning C4624   50  'ssu::Variable': destructor was implicitly defined as deleted
variable.h      Warning C4624   60  'ssu::GenericArray::Block': destructor was implicitly defined as deleted
variable.h      Error   C2079   36  'ssu::Variable::_array' uses undefined class 'ssu::GenericArray'
variable.h      Warning C4624   50  'ssu::Variable': destructor was implicitly defined as deleted
variable.h      Warning C4624   60  'ssu::GenericArray::Block': destructor was implicitly defined as deleted
variable.cpp    Error   C2280   7   'ssu::GenericArray::Block::Block(void)': attempting to reference a deleted function
variable.cpp    Error   C2280   8   'ssu::Variable &ssu::Variable::operator =(const ssu::Variable &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

Comment: Please show the errors you are getting.

Comment: This: `Dictionary<std::string, Variable&> _dict;` as references can not be copied then `_dict` can not be copied etc out through the enclosing classes.

Comment: Not an answer: if C++17 is an option, maybe look at [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Comment: It's *destructors*, not *deconstructors*. Just trying to help you improve your terminology / language in the future.

Comment: @RichardCritten I don't understand what you mean. Is it about the same problem with having non-static data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Union declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union)

Unions cannot contain a non-static data member with a non-trivial special member function (copy constructor, copy-assignment operator, or destructor).

If a union contains a non-static data member with a non-trivial special member function (copy/move constructor, copy/move assignment, or **destructor**), that function **is deleted by default** in the union and needs to be defined explicitly by the programmer.

If a union contains **a non-static data member with a non-trivial default constructor, the default constructor of the union is deleted by default** unless a variant member of the union has a default member initializer.

Such non-static data members with non-trivial default constructors are std::string and Dictionary.

If a class data member has the deleted constructor, the class default constructor is deleted by default.

Comment: Heh, didn't even know that was a thing. I guess I gotta thing of a new way to support strings, arrays, and maps.